# When i try to merge Layout page But it shown as an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at '/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml': 'Scripts'. To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.EnsureRenderedBodyOrSections()

i tried to given view page to layout but the layout page render section showned as error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtn52.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

Comment: Add Layout page to @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)